# analyzing apache logs in production

Tags: apache-http-server, logging

I am analyzing apache logs for errors regularly. My go to tools are `tail` and some combination of `cat` and `grep`.  The process is no where near optimal. For example, it is hard to see where a new error begins and the previous ends due to some errors spanning multiple lines.

How do pros keep an eye on apache error logs? I am using PHP7.x as backend language.

Comment: Loggly or Nagios methinks. More here https://www.dnsstuff.com/apache-log-analyzer-tools

Comment: Always used awk, the start of a new entry is easy recognizable.  I found the errors of the backend applications much more of a challenge.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/630335